# Qual unidade utilizada no iTextsharp.text.pdf C# ScaleAbsolute()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso dimensionar o tamanho de algumas imagens que estou gerando em PDF, vi que existe o método ScaleAbsolute(float newWidth, float newHeight);
eu tenho a medida das imagens em cm e gostaria de saber qual é a unidade que esse método aceita para poder converter.

Comment: Eu imagino que seja em pixels, mas tu poderias olhar na documentação para ter certeza...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em uma simples pequisa na internet: [iTextSharp](https://dotnet.developpez.com/articles/itextsharp/?msclkid=58347e59bb2311ecbf45b6898e54155f)

Basicamente é isso:
Os tamanhos das margens são expressos em pontos tipográficos (ppi ou dpi). O padrão no Windows é 72 dpi. Então você terá que fazer algumas contas para criar margens personalizadas.

Ex: a página A4 (21x29,7).

21 / 2,54 = 8,2677 polegadas

8,2677 x 72 = 595 pontos

29,7 / 2,54 = 11,6929 polegadas? 842 pontos.

A margem padrão é 36 dpi (1/2 polegada) Para uma margem padrão de 1,5 cm, isso corresponde a 42 pontos.

NB: ao contrário da alteração do tamanho da página (que entra em vigor na página seguinte), a alteração da margem é imediata.